# Moving chord on the simple closed curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry

Consider a simple closed curve $C$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For any points $a$ and $b$ on this curve we associate point $c$ on the left (or right) side to chord $ab$ such that $\angle acb = 90^{\circ}, ac=cb.$
Continuously moving (sliding) a chord $ab$ in such a way that it goes to $ba$ (and $a(t)$ never equals $b(t)$, i.e. $\|a(t)-b(t)\|>0 ~\forall t$), the point $c$ will draw a line $L$.
My hypothesis is that **for any** such trajectory and for any $C$, $L$ will intersect $C$. Is it true?
[image]

My intuition says that curve $L$ can never be completely inside or outside $C$, but I don't now how to prove it, because geometry is not not my domain.

P.S. Curve $C$ can be non smooth.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Surely for the outside case you can just take a circle and keep the length of the chord $ab$ small and fixed?

Comment: @James Smith: No, you can't keep the length small and fixed. It must become a diameter at least once. More precisely, for the circle the problem itself makes sense only if the initial chord is a diameter. Then if you shorten your chord, move it around half a circle, and blow up again, you can realize a solution in which C lies completely outside or completely inside (except at the beginning and at the end, when it is on the boundary). See my answer below.

Comment: Forgive me then I don't think I read the question quite carefully enough (although I certainly did try). I thought it was a bit too easy...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you may make the chord close to the curve, and then transport wherever you want:[image]

Comment: The above sketch works for both the 'outside case' and 'inside case', for most smooth curves with good initial position.

Comment: Notice that in the non-smooth 'solution 1' it is crucial that there is *at most one* acute angle. Indeed, if there are two, and the region bounded is convex, there is no way to make C stay on the outside, as you predicted.

Comment: Ok, thx. I will reformulate my question and I'll create new topic in few minutes. Pls look at it too )